# Rotate an Image Continuously

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I want to rotate an image continuously on page load. Code works fine for 1 rotation on page load but to achieve the same effect continuously I have included the `.play()` statement in an infinite while loop as shown below. But it causes the page to hang and nothing shows up.

```
while (i == 1)
{
    if (rotEff.isPlaying != true)
    {
        rotEff.play();
    }
}
```

Any pointers on how to achieve this effect would be of great help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the `repeatCount` property of your `Effect` object to 0 so that it repeats indefinitely:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:Rotate id="rotate" target="{image}" angleBy="360" duration="1000" repeatCount="0" autoCenterTransform="true"></s:Rotate>
</fx:Declarations>
```

**[UPDATE]**

In response to sandy's comment:

> thanks taurayi...setting repeatCount solved the issue..However there
>   is a little bit of transition lag from one complete 360 round to
>   another round..is it feasible to get rid of that also..?

Set the `easer` property to null like so:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:Rotate id="rotate" target="{image}" angleBy="360" duration="1000" repeatCount="0" autoCenterTransform="true" easer="{null}"></s:Rotate>
</fx:Declarations>
```

Comment: thanks taurayi...setting repeatCount solved the issue..However there is a little bit of transition lag from one complete 360 round to another round..is it feasible to get rid of that also..?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. Just set up an enter frame listener to operate as load occurs (don't use timeline animation).

```
obj.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, doRotate);

function doRotate(e:Event):void{
    obj.rotation += 1; //in whatever direction / orientation / increment you wish
}
```

when load is done, just remove the listener.

Comment: this obj is object of image...? Can u expain it more, how its to be done...? I need to add the event listner at creation complete and how is it to be removed...

Comment: obj is the instance name of whatever object (movie clip / bitmap / etc) you wish to move. Add it right after you add the instance into the display list (onto the stage), and when whatever is loading has completed its load process, just `obj.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, doRotate);` to remove it. as3 101.

Comment: hmmm...earlier i was using a rotate class in action script to set the image to rotate from center. public function rotateImgEffect(img:Image):void{
    var rotEff:Rotate = new Rotate();
    //img is the ID of Image component in MXML file
    rotEff.target = img;
    
    rotEff.originX = img.width/2;
    rotEff.originY = img.height/2;
    
    rotEff.duration = 5500;
    rotEff.angleFrom = img.rotation;
    rotEff.angleTo = img.rotation + 360;
    rotEff.play();
    
    
   } How can i set it now...?

Comment: and also if i remove the eventlistner the image just remains static after initial little bit transition

Comment: @Bosworth99 I think there might be a bit of confusion between the two of you because you may be referring to an AS3 project whereas sandy may be referring to a Flex project, but I could be wrong.

Comment: this is old school frame based animation, i suggest time-based via the  so that the frame rate doesnt affect the rotation.  @Taurayi- its flagged as flex, and using a rotateEffect instance, it's probably indeed flex.

Comment: Eh - sure enough. Yeah, definitely flagged Flex. Though the post itself could be read as as3 (if someone answered it before they had their coffee ;) Lol. Anyway...  @Taurayi got it right.

Comment: @Bosworth honestly I wouldn't have realized if I didn't read the comments. I originally was going to answer with the same answer as yours but when I saw the code in sandy's comment(3rd comment) I realized that this sounded more like using effects on `IVisualElement` objects in the flex framework.

Answer (score -1):

If this is Flex application, I would recommend you use `Timer` object.